# Java calendar not working correctly

Tags: java, calendar, output

My task is to make a calendar based on the user's input which is the first day. If the year eg. 2 = Tuesday and the year so I can figure out if it is a leap year. I managed to get everything working except the following case:

When I input 2013 2(meaning that January 1st should be a Tuesday), it places the first of January on a Saturday. You can check if the dates are showing up correctly by going to the calendar on your computer and comparing. I have looked through the code but cannot figure out how the 2 entered in the start results in the dates starting on Saturday.

Where am I going wrong?

```
package javaapplication6;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class JavaApplication6 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the year and the day as a number eg. 2034 2: ");
        int year = input.nextInt();
        int day = input.nextInt();
        day -= 1;
        boolean leap = year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++){
            String wDay = "";
            String wMonth = "";
            int days = 0;
            int current = 0;
            switch(i){
                case 1: days = 31; day+= 31; wMonth = "January"; break;
                case 2: if(leap){days = 29;}else{days = 28;};  if(leap){day += 29;}else{day += 28;}; wMonth = "February"; break;
                case 3: days = 31;  day+= 31; wMonth = "March"; break;
                case 4: days = 30;  day+= 30; wMonth = "April"; break;
                case 5: days = 31;  day+= 31; wMonth = "May"; break;
                case 6: days = 30;  day+= 30; wMonth = "June"; break;
                case 7: days = 31;  day+= 31; wMonth = "July"; break;
                case 8: days = 31;  day+= 31; wMonth = "August"; break;
                case 9: days = 30;  day+= 30; wMonth = "September"; break;
                case 10: days = 31;  day+= 31; wMonth = "October"; break;
                case 11: days = 30;  day+= 30; wMonth = "November"; break;
                case 12: days = 31;  wMonth = "December"; break;
            }
            System.out.printf("   %15s\n", wMonth);
            System.out.println("   ___________________________");
            System.out.printf("   %3s %3s %3s %3s %3s %3s %3s\n", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");
            for(int space = 0; space <= (day % 7) + 1; space++){
                System.out.print("    ");
                current ++;
            }

            for(int date = 1; date <= days; date++){
                if(current > 7){
                    System.out.print("\n    ");
                    current = 1;
                }
                if(date < 10){
                    System.out.print(date + "   ");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(date + "  ");
                }
                current++;
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it worked? I run it for 2014 and 3 and it started with Sunday.
I've made some changes, and now I think it works as it should:

```
    switch(i){
        case 1: days = 31; day+= 0; wMonth = "January"; break;
        case 2: if(leap){days = 29;}else{days = 28;};  day += 31; wMonth = "February"; break;
        case 3: days = 31;  if(leap){day += 29;}else{day += 28;}; wMonth = "March"; break;
        case 4: days = 30;  day+= 31; wMonth = "April"; break;
        case 5: days = 31;  day+= 30; wMonth = "May"; break;
        case 6: days = 30;  day+= 31; wMonth = "June"; break;
        case 7: days = 31;  day+= 30; wMonth = "July"; break;
        case 8: days = 31;  day+= 31; wMonth = "August"; break;
        case 9: days = 30;  day+= 31; wMonth = "September"; break;
        case 10: days = 31;  day+= 30; wMonth = "October"; break;
        case 11: days = 30;  day+= 31; wMonth = "November"; break;
        case 12: days = 31;  day+= 30; wMonth = "December"; break;
    }
```

and

```
 for(int space = 0; space <= (day % 7); space++){ //here u added one space too much.
```

In your switch statement you added days too quickly. And in the first month you already had day=31 but you should have had the number of days from the input - 1.